# Storing jQuery $.get function returned data to class global variable

Tags: jquery, json, class, variables

How to I get jQuery $.get to store json data retrieve into the class variable industry or product?

If you look at the data returned from the $.get call to a php file, then it does return a jSon array and yes I could use the information then, but it's more important for me to store what is returned in the global variables of class Profile.

```
Profile=new Profile("kazie.php");
Profile.getProfile(0123, 'Kayla', 'kayla@email.com');

var Profile = function(php_file){
    this.php_file=php_file;
    this.serial;
    this.industry;
    this.product;
    //Also need to access scope as well 
};

Profile.prototype={

    getProfile:function(serial, name, email){

        $.get(this.php_file,{action: "retrieve_profile", serial: serial, name: name, email: email},
            function (data){ //Return a json array of our new profile
                    //Data is an array of properties. array("industry"=>"Retail");
                   //I need to assign these properties to my global variables for
                    //***How to I get data["industry"] to store in Profile.industry?**


                }, "json"
            );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the [.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) function will give you some ideas on how to process the returned JSON (note that you don't need to switch to this function, they're equivalent given you've specified "json", .getJSON is a convenience method). It explains it better than I could.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
function (data){
          Profile.prototype.industry = data.industry
     }, "json"
);
...
```

This should store the industry into the prototype of your class. If you do not want to store it into the prototype (which would make it available in all instances), then you need to store it only the instance you need it to.